# Can I create a regular expression with a backreference that matches the opposite case

Tags: .net, regex

I need to match a pattern that starts with a capital letter, is followed by a series of the same letter in lowercase, and then ends with the same letter capitalized again.

Should Match:

```
XxxxX
NnN
YyyyyyyY
```

Should Not Match:

```
XyyyX
XxxxB
XyyyZ
```

I know how to match the two capital letters using backreferences, but I'm not sure how to capture the middle portion where the letter needs to be the same but a different case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it all in a single regular expression. You can test most of it using a regular expression, but you need a separate test to see if the upper and lower case letters are the same:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(s, @"^([A-Z])([a-z])+\1$");
if (match.Success && match.Groups[1].Value.Equals(match.Groups[2].Value,
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
    // OK
}
```

Note: Here I'm assuming that you only want A-Z.

Comment: I assumed that might be the case. Thanks for the answer. I didn't think of putting the '+' outside of a grouping, that makes the equality test much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **non**-regex answer.

```
    if (char.IsUpper(subjectString[0])
        && char.IsLetter(subjectString[0])
        && subjectString[0].Equals(subjectString[subjectString.Length - 1])
        && subjectString.Substring(1, subjectString.Length - 2).All(x => x.Equals(char.ToLower(subjectString[0]))))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }
```

Comment: This would work. But I wasn't thorough in my question. This pattern will actually be part of a bigger string and I want to quickly find these and do some sanitation on them before passing them off to be processed. So it would be a bit more complicated to do it manually like this. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @NerdFury No problem. Just wanted to illustrate that for tasks such as these regex may not be the only solution. In addition for big strings this solution may actually be faster.